# While loop multiple conditions not working

Tags: python

I tried to add a condition to where if the while loop meets a "Y" or "y" it will still move the letters to the end, but keep "Y" or "y" at the beginning, yet the loop will end and just add "ay"

```
print("Pig Latin Translator Test!")
name = raw_input("What is your name, friend?")
if len(name) > 0 and name.isalpha():
    print("Hello!")
else:
    print("That's not a name!")
word = raw_input("What is your word?")
VOWELS = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
YList = ("Y", "y")
if word[0] in VOWELS:
    word = word + "yay"
else:
```

This is the section causing problems:

```
    while word[0] in YList or (not VOWELS):
        word = word[1:] + word[0]
    word = word + "ay"
print (word)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python pig latin converter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400008/python-pig-latin-converter)

Comment: Why do you use both capital and lowercase characters for the vowels instead of using the `.upper()` and `.lower()` functions?

Comment: It is a pig latin converter;However, it is not a duplicate of that code.

Comment: And I didn't think of calling on those functions actually

Answer (score 1):

The value of `(not VOWELS)` is always falsy because `VOWELS` is truthy.

You meant to write:

```
while word[0] in YList or (word[0] not in VOWELS):
```