# Pig Latin Function Sentence

Tags: python, function

THe rules for the pig latin sentences are:

1.for words beginning with consonants, all letters before the ﬁrst vowel are moved to the     end of the word, and is further appended by 'ay'
2.for words that begin with vowels, the word is appended by 'hay'
3.for words that do not contain a vowel, the ﬁrst letter is moved to the end of the word and is appended with 'way'
4. all non characters (i.e., numbers, symbols) are ignored

The main part of the code executes an inﬁnite loop that takes a string input from the user, invokes the pigLatin function and prints the result returned. The pigLatin function receives a list of words as its input and converts them to pig latin using the rules above. The main part exits when the user input "Quit this program" as the input sentence for conversion. Verify your program for all cases (including invalid inputs) and save your program.

I find it very difficult to solve rule 3. As I test the code, the out put isn't correct...
I struggle it for the whole night and couldn't sleep....Please help
Here is my code:

`enter code here`

```
 sentence=input('input:')
 VOWELS=['a','e','i','o','u']
 CONSONANTS=['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z']
def pigLatin():
    t=-1
    for word in newsentence:

        if word[0] in CONSONANTS:
            if 'a'and'e'and'i'and'o'and'u' not in word[1:]:
                print(word[1:]+word[0]+'way',end=' ')
            for u in word:
                t +=1
                if u in VOWELS:
                    print (word[t:]+word[0:t]+'ay',end=' ')
                break
    elif word[0] in VOWELS:   
         print (word[0:]+'hay',end=' ')  
    else:
         print (word[0:])

while sentence!=('Quit the program'):
newsentence=sentence.split()
pigLatin()
sentence=input('input:')
```

Comment: This is probably already answered a thousand times. It is not `'a' and 'b' in foo`, but `'a' in foo and 'b' in foo`...

Comment: "All non characters are ignored", did you mean that only letters are taken into account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pig latin converter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400008/python-pig-latin-converter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Willem Van Onsem said, this line doesn't do what you think:

```
 if 'a'and'e'and'i'and'o'and'u' not in word[1:]:
```

You should try experimenting with the interpreter.

```
'a' and 'e' not in "bar"
# returns True
```

This is happening because and is a logical operator which looks at what comes before and after it. It is doing this:

```
'a' and ('e' not in "bar")
```

which evaluates to

```
'a' and True
```

which evaluates to True, because non-empty strings get assigned the boolean True.

Here is something that will work. It uses the all function, which only returns True if all of its elements are true, and a feature of Python called comprehension which allows you to do tidy loops:

```
vowels = "aeiou"

all(char not in vowels for char in word)
```